# How can I rewrite my macro to work well with IDE auto-format?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a macro. But my IDE completely messes up the indentation:

```cpp
void fn()
{
   MY_MACRO(true)
            {
                 // more code here
            }
}
```

The odd indentation by the IDE is (probably) by design since the macro after expansion becomes:

```cpp
void fn()
{
    for(...)
       if( ... ) { return; }
       else 
            for( ... )
            {
                // more code here
            }
}
```

My question: Can I rewrite my macro to get the auto indentation to look nicer?

I want to change my code, not modify the IDE settings. If it looks ugly for me out-of-the-box, it will look ugly for others out-of-the-box. I want my code to look pretty and work well with IDE auto formatting (especially IDE default settings).

Simplified, the macro does this:

Case 1:

```cpp
void f() 
{
    // Executes the code inside the scope
    MY_MACRO(false) 
    {
        std::cout << "This line gets printed\n";
    }
}
```

Case 2:

```cpp
void f() 
{
    // Executes the code inside the scope, then executes a return to exit the function (which is always void(...))
    MY_MACRO(true) 
    {
        std::cout << "This line gets printed\n";
    }
    std::cout << "This line does not get printed\n";
}
```

Case 3:

```cpp
void f() 
{
    // Will act like a return statement;
    MY_MACRO(true);
    std::cout << "This line does not get printed\n";
}
```

My current implementation is (simplified):

```cpp
#define MY_MACRO( expression ) for(int i=0; i<3; ++i) if( (i>0) && (expression) ) { return; } else for(; i == 0; ++i)
```

Contrains:

- I prefer C++ 11. But newer versions are OK if it is not possible in 11.
- No throwing exceptions!

EDIT: Clearification: The three cases represents code which already exists and which I cannot change. And its behaviour has to remain as desribed. What I *can* change is the implementation of MY_MACRO. And it does not have to be a macro. It can be anything.

Something like the following would work, but throws an exception, which I would like to avoid:

```cpp
void g(bool b) { if(b) throw new Someting(); return true; }
#define MY_MACRO(X) for(int i=0; i==0 && g(X); ++i)
```

The following is not valid c++, so that doesn't work:

```cpp
#define MY_MACRO(X) for(int i=0; i==0 && ( (X) ? (return, 1) : 1) ; ++i)
```

Comment: Use a function instead of a macro and the problem will go away.

Comment: macros are never beautiful, no matter how hard you try. Did you consider not using a macro?

Comment: Code is meant to be read by **other** humans. However you may think your macro makes your code "cleaner", it just makes it basically unreadable to anyone else until they've learned what your convention is.

Comment: Whenever you can write a proper function rather than a macro, you *should*. Don't write macros - please.

Comment: Off topic: Not using a macro is not an option.

Comment: You may want to add a tag for which IDE you are using...

Comment: You want to rewrite the macro so that your IDE formatter won't reformat it the way it does right now. Why now change formatter settings instead? Still, as the question is tagged with C++, in 90% of the cases you should use function instead of a macro.

Comment: Clearification: Not using macros (e.g. templates) is perfectly OK. But the final result must look and function exactly as the examples (to be compatible with already exisitng code which is not going to change).

Comment: The quiestion is more if it is possible in c++ to write the same functionality in _one_ level of scopes rather that in 3 levels (for-if-for). Or by template-magic. Or ... something.